# How do I get the user id and using it to post new comment in the store method in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

This code does not seem to capture the user id from the session so I can use it as a foreign key in the database for the place the user is adding a comment to.

```js
public function store(Request $request, $place_id) {

  // find place in the database
  $place = Place::find($place_id);

  // find user in the database
  $user = User::find(\Auth::id());

  // create review instance
  $review = new Review([
    'review' => request('review'),
    'rating' => request('rating')
  ]);

  // save review (creating relationship) in the places table as reviews
  $place - > reviews() - > save($review);

  // save review (creating relationship) in the users table as reviews
  $user - > reviews() - > save($review);

  $reviewData = Review::find($review - > id);

  if (request() - > wantsJson()) {
    return $reviewData; // Returns JSON, thanks to Laravel Magic™
  }

  // return view
  return view('place');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating models for relationships, use `create` instead of `save`.

```
$user->reviews()->create($review);
```

The `create` method will associate the relevant relationship id.

I can see that you are saving the `$review` twice. Once in `place_reviews` and once in `user_reviews`. Consider changing your database logic, so `reviews` *belongs to* `User` and `Place` instead. This would be a lot more sensible structure:

**Controller**

```
 $review = new Review([
    'review' => request('review'),
    'rating' => request('rating')
 ]);

 $review->user()->associate($user);
 $review->place()->associate($place);

 $review->save();
```

**Review model**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function place()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Place::class);
}
```

**Review table**

```
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
$table->unsignedInteger('place_id');
```

**User and place model**

```
public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Review::class);
}
```

You also have the option to use *belongs to many* relationships, if *one* `Review` could relate to *multiple* `Place`.

Another tip:

You may also consider using `findOrFail` to ensure your user is valid. This way your code will throw an `Exception` if there is no user id, as opposed to proceeding with a `null` user, which could be cause for hard-to-find errors.

```
$userId = \Auth::id();
$user = User::findOrFail($userId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this.

```
   $user = \Auth::user();
    if(!is_null($user)){

    $user_id = $user->id;

}
```